# Not sure how to create and anchor to a div when typing in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I created an AngularJS application that filters a list under the input box when you type more than one character in the input box. This input box is toward the middle of the page and I would like it to jump to the top of the page when a user is typing into it. I'm not sure how to achieve this. I'm pretty new to jquery and Angular so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: A little bit code would be more better, please could you add some code?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
```

to go to the top of the page whenever user types watch for the event

```
$scope.watch('mg-model',function(val){
 };)
```

and when val is null or empty take any div id inside textbox is wrapped and animate

Answer (score 0):

I would create a directive for you input field. Something like this:

```
.directive('query', function() {
    return {
        restrict:"A",
        replace: true,
        template: "<input type='text' ng-model='query'>",
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            elem.bind('input', function() {
                elem.css({'top':'10px','position':'fixed'});
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can just stick `<div query></div>` wherever your original input field was. I tested it and it worked well for me. Directives are the angular way to DOM manipulations like this. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I should have explained my question more clearly. This worked for me as well, but I would like the whole page to move up with it instead of just the input box. I would like it to look like the user just scrolled to where the filter results were, so if the user scrolled back to the top, it would appear as if nothing has changed. Just like a plain old HTML anchor. Could you explain how to do that?